# oracle sql convert time from timestamp to hhmm

Tags: sql, oracle, time, timestamp, extract

I hope you can help

I am trying to extract the time from a timestamp in this format HHMM in Oracle SQL

I'm currently using this statement

> to_number(to_char(g.start_time,'hh24mi'))

It works to a certain extent, but times from 00:00 - 09:59 don't appear as i would like it to do.

For example 00:00 is currently being extracted a single 0 but I need it in four digits 0000 same with 09:59 appears as 959 but I would like it as 0959

do you have any suggestions

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't try to convert it to a number since number will ignore any leading 0. Just use `to_char()`

`to_char(g.start_time,'hh24mi')`

Answer (score 0):

If you need four digits, leave it as a string:

```
to_char(g.start_time, 'hh24mi')
```

Numbers don't care about leading zeros.